# How to have loader widget block only some content

Tags: magento2, javascript, widget, loader

The [loader widget](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_loader.html) allows a developer to block page content while an AJAX request is ongoing. The devdocs describes it as:

> The Loader widget blocks page content (all content or a part of it).

I'm having trouble figuring out how to block "a part of it."

By using `showLoader: true` in jQuery AJAX calls, you can have the widget automatically show and hide the loader through the lifetime of the request. Further, the `loaderContext` property is supposed to give the ability to have the loader appear in a specific area on the site - which seems like a good lead. (You can see an example in [the reviews processing](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/9544fb243d5848a497d4ea7b88e08609376ac39e/app/code/Magento/Review/view/frontend/web/js/process-reviews.js#L20-L21) JS).

```js
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  showLoader: true,
  loaderContext: $('.elem')
  // snip
)};
```

This doesn't work at all, in my experience – I just get a warning of `Expected to start loader but did not find one in the dom` when I use my own element there.

What gives? Do I need to make another instance of the Loader widget for every section I want it to hide?

Comment: I also facing same. Did you solve this problem?

Comment: No, sorry. But I do know Magento 2 better since I asked this question! Looking at the JS code for lib/web/mage/loader.js, I can see that context only just calls trigger('processStart'); on the element passed to the setting. That shows me that you probably do have to instantiate a new Loader widget.

Answer (score 0):

try this, I have this working on my code and it seems to be the easiest way to have the loader going nicely

```
   $.ajax({
      url: url,
      beforeSend: function () {
         $('body').trigger('processStart');
      },
      success: function (res) {
         // snip 
         $('body').trigger('processStop');
       }
      )};
```

Comment: Not sure if you read the question - I want to have the loader activate on a specific part of the page. This would activate it on the body, which I do not want.

Comment: I thought you were trying to freeze your screen, I overlooked the fact you wanted to freeze a specific part. I’ll have another go likely this weekend